# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n \right)\cdot \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right)= 1$ WITHOUT computing the sum

Tags: limits, summation, gamma-function

That's it. I want to know a way to do it so i can use it to prove other results like this ones:
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^2} \right)\cdot \sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} \right)= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^m} \right)\cdot \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1/m} \right)= \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)}{m}$$

Comment: What if you replace the sum with an integral and show that that's valid in the limit?

Comment: How? I don't really get what you mean, sorry...

Comment: The first one ($~$with $x = 1 - \epsilon~$): $\epsilon^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\epsilon z^{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\,\,\,\stackrel{\mathrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\to} {\sqrt{\pi} \over 2}$. The second one follows a similar pattern.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. Assume $m>0$ and $0<x<1$. The function $t \mapsto e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t^m}$ being *monotone decreasing* over $[1,\infty)$, one deduces
$$
\int_1^\infty e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t^m}\,dt\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^m} \le x+\int_1^\infty e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t^m}\,dt
$$ then one may *evaluate*
$$
\int_1^\infty e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t^m}\,dt.
$$ For example,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t}\,dt&=-\frac{x}{\ln x},
\\\\
\int_1^\infty e^{-(-\ln x)\cdot t^2}\,dt&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{-\ln x}\right)}{2\sqrt{-\ln x}}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it now :)