# About the asymptotic behavior of specific Jacobi $\theta$ function $\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0;x\right)$ when $x\to{1-}$.

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics, theta-functions

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{n^2}}=\dfrac{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)-1}2$ for $x\in\left(0,1\right)$ (just in case), it suffices to consider the former below. (Another relevant identity is that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{n^2}}=\left(1-x\right)\mspace{-2mu}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\!\left\lfloor\mspace{-1mu}\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor\!x^n}$.)
Many a post (e.g.,

1. [What is $\lim_{x\to1^{-}} (1-x)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i^2}\right)^{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739670),
2. [Why is $\lim_{x\to 1}\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}=\sqrt{\pi}/2\,\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887632),
3. [Compute the limit of $\sqrt{1-a}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} a^{n^2}$ when $a\to1^-$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179249),
4. [$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}\ \left(1+x+x^4+x^9+x^{16}+x^{25}+\cdots\right)=\sqrt{\pi}/2$ is true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156392), and
5. [How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n \right)\cdot \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right)= 1$ WITHOUT computing the sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226563))

has shown that
$$\lim_{\mspace{-1mu}x\to1^-}{\sqrt{1-x\mspace{2mu}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\mspace{-1.5mu}x^{n^2}}}=\frac{\mspace{-1.5mu}\sqrt\pi\mspace{1mu}}2\text{.}$$ Nevertheless, none of them evaluated the limit $$\lim_{\mspace{-1mu}x\to1^-}{\mspace{-3mu}\left({\sqrt{\mspace{-0.5mu}\frac\pi{1-x}}-2\mspace{-0.75mu}\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\mspace{-1.75mu}x^{n^2}}}\right)\mspace{-1mu}}\text{,}$$ which is equal to $1$. [how to find the asymptotic expansion of the following sum:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/569654) sketched out a possible approach to finding this kind of limit. Some other related posts are as follows:

1. [Asymptotics of a recurrence relation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212706),
2. [Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{b^n}$ when $x\to1^-$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092164),
3. [Evaluate $\lim_{x\to1^-}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(x^{(2^n)}\right)-\log_2\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296066) and
4. [What's the limit of the series $\log_2(1-x)+x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\cdots$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864987).

In [Analysis of Series and Products. Part 1: The Euler–Maclaurin Formula](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2021.1845542) and [Analysis of Series and Products. Part 2: The Trapezoidal Rule](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2021.1859323), the authors show that $${{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mathrm{e}^{-j^2/x^2}-\frac{x\sqrt\pi}2+\frac12}\to0}\quad\text{as}\quad{x\to{+\infty}}\text{,}$$ and the magnitude of the left-hand side decreases exponentially as $x$ increases. (Then set $u=\exp\left(-x^{-2}\right)$. How about the Abel–Plana formula?)

In addition, in [On the asymptotics of some partial theta functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-017-9893-6) and [Some new asymptotic expansions of certain partial theta functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-013-9499-6), each author showes that $$\dfrac{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)+1}2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{x^{n^2}}=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{-\pi}{\ln{x}}}+\frac12+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(\ln^q{\!x}\right)\text{,}\quad\forall{q\in\mathbb{N_+}}\text{,}$$ as $x\to1^-$ (after making some substitutions).

It is generally known that $\ln{x}\sim{x-1}$ as $x\to1$; hence, as $x\to1^-$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{n^2}}\sim\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}$ just means that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^{n^2}}\sim\frac12\sqrt{\frac{-\pi}{\ln{x}}}$. Yet, if one uses the former in the asymptotic expansion, what about the remainder term?

Via a number of numerical experiments, it *seems* that $$\frac{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(1-x\right)}}=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(1-x\right)}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{x^{n^2}}=\frac1{1-x}-\frac14+\operatorname{\mathcal{o}}\left(1\right)\quad\text{as}\quad{x\to1^-}\text{.}$$ Unfortunately, I have **no** idea how to prove it. Any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: Updated for much better.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{x^{n^2}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-n^2\ln\frac{1}{x}}}=\theta(\frac{1}{\pi}\ln\frac{1}{x})$$
Then you can use the functional equation for theta-function (which is $\mathbf{exact}$; for the reference - http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/fourier-analysis/theta-zeta.pdf , page 4):
$$\theta (x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-\pi x n^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\theta\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-\frac{\pi n^2}{x}}}$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{x^{n^2}}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{|\ln x|}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-\frac{\pi^2 n^2}{|\ln x|}}}$$

Comment: At $x=1-\epsilon; \epsilon\to 0$$$\ln (1-\epsilon)=-(\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon^3+ ...)$$
All the terms, except for $n=0$, are exponentially small; therefore we leave the only term with $n=0$
$$S=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}{x^{n^2}}\sim\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon+\frac{1}{3}\epsilon^2+... }}$$
Then you can easily get the series, expanding the square root:
$$S=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\Big(1-\frac{\epsilon}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\epsilon^2}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\big)^2+ O(\epsilon^3)\Big)$$

Comment: corrected the typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering$$f(x)=\frac{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(1-x\right)}}$$
Adaptating an approximation nwork done in my group more than thirty years ago, ws have
$$g(x)=-\frac{1+2 \left(t+t^4+t^9\right)}{x-1}-\frac{1}{4} \left(1+2
   \left(t+t^4+t^9\right)\right)+$$ $$\frac 1{96}\left(7+14 t+96 t^4+14 t^9\right) (x-1)-\frac{5}{128} \left(1+2
   \left(t+t^4+t^9\right)\right) (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ where
$$t=\exp\Bigg[\pi^2\left(\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x-1}{12}+\frac{1}{24} (x-1)^2-\frac{19}{720}
   (x-1)^3 \right) \Bigg]$$ is very small; for $x=\frac 12$, $t=\exp\Big[ -\frac{8321 }{5760}\pi ^2\Big]=6.43\times 10^{-7}$.

So, using $t=0$, we have as another approximation
$$h(x)=-\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7 }{96}(x-1)-\frac{5}{128}
   (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$

Using $t=0$, we could extend the expansion and have
$$h(x)=-\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7 }{96}(x-1)-\frac{5}{128} (x-1)^2+\frac{309
   }{10240}(x-1)^3-$$ $$\frac{763 }{40960}(x-1)^4+\frac{893209
   }{61931520}(x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$

Using the last $h(x)$, consider the norm
$$\Phi=\int_{\frac 12}^{1} \Big[f(x)-h(x)\Big]^2\,dx=9.80 \times 10^{-9}$$

**Edit**

I have been in touch with my former PhD student who continued working in this area. His latest results are
$$\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)=\sqrt{\frac \pi t}\Bigg[1-\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,t^n\Bigg]\qquad \text{with}\qquad t=1-x$$ where the $a_n$ form the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{7}{24},\frac{5}{32},\frac{787}{7680},\frac{763}{10240},\frac{893209}{15482880},\frac{2885597}{61931520},\frac{1153151299}{29727129600},\frac{261937547}{7927234560},\frac{3997632829}{139519328256},\frac{30141297349}{1195879956480},\frac{4101
   190700056349}{182826127746662400},\cdots\right\}$$ This makes

$$f(x)=\frac{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(1-x\right)}}=\frac 1{1-x} -\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,(1-x)^{n-1}$$

Using the above coefficients
$$\Phi=\int_{\frac 12}^{1} \Big[f(x)-h(x)\Big]^2\,dx=7.83 \times 10^{-15}$$

Comment: Thanks, but what is $g(x)$?

Comment: @user688486. $g(x)$ is the first expansion; $h(x)$ is $g(x)$ with $t=0$. Plot the original function and the last $h(x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and tell me what you think.

Comment: Are there any research papers on 'an approximation (n)work done in my group more than thirty years ago'?

Comment: @user688486. This was part of a thesis work. If I remember, it was presented in a condefece around 1977 in the US. By yhe way, if this is an answer for you, may be you could accept it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

We use the fact that the Mellintransform $M$ of a Gaussian is given by

$$
M(e^{-  x^2})=\frac{\Gamma(s/2)}{2}\,\,\,\, (*) 
$$

In following we are using a method discovered by [Flajolet and co-workers](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/mellin-harm.pdf). First of all we can see that the sum in question ($-a^2=\log(x)$)
$$
\mathcal{S}(a)=\sum_n e^{-a^2 n^2}
$$
is a harmonic sum with frequencies $f_n=n$ , amplitudes $A_n=1$ and base function $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Therefore by the above reference we have (using (*) and $\Lambda(s)=\sum_{n\geq1 } f_n^{-s} $):
$$
M(\mathcal{S})=\Lambda(s)g^*(s)=\zeta(s)\frac{\Gamma(s/2)}{2}
$$

now we can use the "Mellin Summation Formula" stated on page 25 of the reference ($H$ is the set of residues left of the fundamental strip $(0,\infty)$ ).
$$
\mathcal{S}(a)\sim_{a\rightarrow 0} \sum_{s \in H}\text{res}(M(\mathcal S)a^{-s/2})
$$

we have $\text{res}(M(\mathcal S)a^{-s/2})|_{s=1}=\sqrt{\pi}/(2a^{1/2})$ and
$\text{res}(M(\mathcal S)a^{-s/2})|_{s=0}=-1/2$ and therefore
$$
\mathcal{S}(a)\sim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^{1/2}}-\frac12
$$

Note the corrections are expontially small since $\zeta(-2n)=0$ so no other residue has finite value and no further correction of $O(x^n)$ exists.