# Solving for $x$ the equation $\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)=k \qquad (k \geq 1)$

Tags: systems-of-equations, approximation, theta-functions

Trying to answer [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260536/about-the-asymptotic-behavior-of-specific-jacobi-theta-function-operatornam/4260800#4260800), it reminded me a very old problem we faced almost $50$ years ago.

Solve for $x$ the equation

$$\color{red} {\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)=k} \qquad \text{with} \qquad k \geq 1$$

Thanks to Emeritus Prof. Bois and CAS,  using $x=1-t^2$, we have an *approximate* expansion (have a look at my answer in the linked question)
$$\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,1-t^2\right)=\frac{\sqrt{ \pi}} t\Bigg[1-\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,t^{2n}\Bigg]$$
the first twelve coefficients being given in the linked question. So,we have $\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,1-t^2\right)$ given as a series to $O(t^{25})$.

Using the corresponding series reversion to limited order
$$t=\frac{\sqrt \pi } k \Bigg[1-\frac{\pi }{4 k^2}+\frac{5 \pi ^2}{96 k^4}-\frac{\pi ^3}{128 k^6}+\frac{79 \pi
   ^4}{92160 k^8}-\frac{3 \pi ^5}{40960 k^{10}}+\cdots+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{26}}\right)\Bigg]$$ which gives
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^{12} (-1)^n \frac 1{n!}  \left(\frac{\pi}{k^2}\right)^n-\frac{829782456922339}{91413063873331200}\left(\frac{\pi}{k^2}\right)^{13}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{28}}\right)$$
which *looks* to be very close to
$$\color{blue}{x \sim \exp\left(-\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)} \tag 1$$

Checking the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_n^\infty \Bigg[\vartheta _3\left(0,\exp\left(-\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)\right)-k\Bigg]^2 \,dk$$ we have
$$\Phi_1=6.39\times 10^{-4}\qquad \qquad \Phi_2=7.89\times 10^{-12}\qquad \qquad \Phi_3=2.66\times 10^{-25}$$

**My questions**

> - What could be the coefficients $a_n$ ?

> - Can we justify $(1)$ ?

> - Can we improve it ?

**Edit**

Continuing working the approximation on the basis of Mathematica expansion of  $\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)$, I obtained the next level approximation

$$\color{blue}{x \sim \exp\left(-a^2\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)} \qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{a= 1+2 e^{-\pi  k^2}}\tag 2$$ Comparing the norms for small values of $n$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \log(\Phi_{(1)})& \log(\Phi_{(2)}) & \frac{\Phi_{(1)}) }{\Phi_{(2)}) } \\
 1.0 & -3.19473 & -3.92585 & 5 \\
 1.1 & -3.73138 & -4.88028 & 14 \\
 1.2 & -4.32510 & -5.96957 & 44 \\
 1.3 & -4.97563 & -7.18137 & 161 \\
 1.4 & -5.68271 & -8.51021 & 672 \\
 1.5 & -6.44613 & -9.95444 & 3223 \\
 1.6 & -7.26572 & -11.5139 & 17707 \\
 1.7 & -8.14130 & -13.1886 & 111498 \\
 1.8 & -9.07274 & -14.9785 & 804917 \\
 1.9 & -10.0599 & -16.8834 & 6659871
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Details about the process** *(and improvement ?)*

Using $x=1-t^2$, the equation to be solved is
$$\operatorname{\vartheta}_3\left(0,1-t^2\right)=k$$ we have, using the expansion given by Mathematica

$$K=\frac k {A \sqrt \pi}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{4}-\frac{7 t^3}{96}-\frac{5 t^5}{128}-\frac{787
   t^7}{30720}-\frac{763 t^9}{40960}-\frac{893209
   t^{11}}{61931520}+O\left(t^{13}\right)$$

$$t=\frac{1}{K}-\frac{K}{4}-\frac{7 K^3}{96}-\frac{5 K^5}{128}-\frac{787
   K^7}{30720}-\frac{763 K^9}{40960}-\frac{893209
   K^{11}}{61931520}+O\left(K^{13}\right)$$ that is to say
$$x=1-\frac{1}{K^2}+\frac{1}{2 K^4}-\frac{1}{6 K^6}+\frac{1}{24
   K^8}-\frac{1}{120 K^{10}}+\frac{1}{720 K^{12}}-\frac{1}{5040
   K^{14}}+O\left(\frac{1}{K^{16}}\right)$$ that is to say
$$x \sim \exp\left(-\frac 1 {K^2}  \right)=\exp\left(-A^2\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)$$

But, for this level of expansion, we have
$$A=1+2\sum_{n=1}^6 \exp\big[n^2 \,\pi^2\,a\big]$$
$$a=-\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-x}{12}+\frac{1}{24} (1-x)^2+\frac{19}{720}
   (1-x)^3+$$ $$\frac{3}{160} (1-x)^4+\frac{863 (1-x)^5}{60480}+\frac{275
   (1-x)^6}{24192}$$

In this last expression, use as an approximation $x=\exp\left(-\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)$ to approximate the value of $A$. Expanding for large values of $k$, this give
$$a=-\frac{k^2}{\pi }+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{14}}\right)$$ and then
$$A\sim 1+2\sum_{n=1}^6 \exp\big[-n^2 \pi k^2\big]\simeq 1+2 e^{- \pi k^2}$$ which was the previous approximation.

But, we could keep $a$ as it is, replace $x$ by $\exp\left(-\frac \pi {k^2}  \right)$ and just keep $A$ as it is.

**Update**

In fact, $a$ has been later identified as
$$a=-\frac 1{1-x}+\frac 12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty G_n (1-x)^n=\frac 1{\log(x)}$$ where the $G_n$
are Gregory coefficients (or logarithmic numbers) which makes
$$A=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp\big[n^2 \,\pi^2\,a\big]=\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{\frac{\pi ^2}{\log (x)}}\right)$$

**Numerical usage**

It seems potentially interesting to a use a fixed point method based on
$$x_{n+1}=\exp\Bigg[- \Big[A(x_{n-1})\Big]^2 \frac \pi {k^2}\Bigg]$$ Trying  for $k=2$ and starting with $x_0=\exp\left(-\frac \pi {4}  \right)$ , we have the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{0.45593}812776599623677 \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.45593313}260483808317 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.455933131729}15572437 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.4559331317290021}9973 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.45593313172900217281}
\end{array}
\right)$$
which  is the solution.

**Numerical checks**

To check the validity of the approximations, give $x$ a value and compute the corresponding value of $k$ recompute $x$ according to the formulae.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{\text{given}} & x_{(1)} & x_{(2)}\\
 0.20 & 0.202797206493824 & 0.200144745094302 \\
 0.25 & 0.251121636226435 & 0.250025537551774 \\
 0.30 & 0.300397726522987 & 0.300003574197057 \\
 0.35 & 0.350121427002546 & 0.350000376690885 \\
 0.40 & 0.400030778288808 & 0.400000027827736 \\
 0.45 & 0.450006160875082 & 0.450000001305483 \\
 0.50 & 0.500000907841419 & 0.500000000033860 \\
 0.55 & 0.550000088981712 & 0.550000000000398 \\
 0.60 & 0.600000004983438 & 0.600000000000002 \\
 0.65 & 0.650000000125653 & 0.650000000000000 \\
 0.70 & 0.700000000000959 & 0.700000000000000 \\
 0.75 & 0.750000000000001 & 0.750000000000000 \\
 0.80 & 0.800000000000000 & 0.800000000000000 \\
 0.85 & 0.850000000000000 & 0.850000000000000 \\
 0.90 & 0.900000000000000 & 0.900000000000000 \\
 0.95 & 0.950000000000000 & 0.950000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with relation between complete elliptic integral of the first kind (notation as in *Wolfram Mathematica* EllipticK function)
$$
K(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-m \sin^2 t}}
$$
It [can be expressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Relation_to_Jacobi_theta_function) in terms of $\vartheta_3$
$$
K(m) = \frac{\pi}{2} \vartheta_3^2(0, q)
$$
and $q$ and $m$ are related by
$$
q = \exp \left(-\pi \frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}\right)
$$
In terms of the original question we have to solve
$$
K(m) = \frac{\pi}{2} k^2
$$
for $m$ and then evaluate $x = \exp\left(-\pi \frac{K(1-m)}{K(m)}\right) = 
 \exp\left(-\frac{2 K(1-m)}{k^2}\right)$.

Observe that the original approximation $x = \exp(-\pi/k^2)$ corresponds to plugging $K(1-m) \approx \pi/2$.

Using rough approximation
$$
K(m) \approx \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \log (1-m)\\
K(1-m) \approx \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \log m \approx
\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \log \left[1 - \exp(\pi - 2K(m))\right]
$$
results into an improved formula that looks like
$$
x = \exp\left(
-\frac{\pi - \log(1 - \exp(\pi - \pi k^2))}{k^2}
\right) = 
\exp(-\pi/k^2) \left(
1 - \exp(\pi(1-k^2))
\right)^{1/k^2}
$$
It improves $\Phi_1$ norm by an order of magnitude.

Anyway, in my opinion for these types of problems numerical inversion or tabular methods are better. These kind of problems are addressed in 17 chapter of Abramowitz and Stegun.

Comment: Thank you ! I missed the relation with $K$. Cheers and (+1) for sure. By the way, this is just for the art for art's sake,

Comment: I have found a next level approximation. If you don't mind, would you accept to have a look at my edit ? Tahnks again & cheers. :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Impressive. How did you manage to collapse the series into such rather complex form?

Comment: I shall try to edit.

Comment: I added a bunch of details.

Comment: Have a look at the fixed point iteration !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Is it so good near $k = 1$?

Comment: Have a look at my last edit and tell me what you think about it. Notice that for $x=0.2$, $k=1.4032$.