# A "surprising" asymptotic inverse of $\vartheta _3(0,x)$

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, inverse-function, theta-functions

After [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266487/solving-for-x-the-equation-operatorname-vartheta-3-left0-x-right-k-qqua) of mine related to the problem of approximate solutions of
$$\large\color{red}{\operatorname{\vartheta}_3}\left(0,x\right)=k$$ when $k$ is large, continuing the previous work (*just for the art for art's sake*) thanks to @uranix's answer and suggestions, I ended with tha approximate asymptotic inverse
$$\large x=\exp\left(-A^2\frac{\pi  }{k^2} \right)\qquad \text{where} \qquad A=\color{red}{\vartheta _3}\left(0,e^{-\pi  k^2}\right)$$ which is quite good as soon as $k \geq 1.5$ (for this value the error is $6.20\times 10^{-5}$).

Concerning the norm
$$\Phi=\int_{\frac 32}^\infty \big[{\vartheta}_3\left(0,x\right)-k\big]^2\,dk=1.11\times 10^{-10}$$

What is surprising (at least to me) is to see the inverse function involving the function itself.

**Do we know similar cases ?**

Comment: @gary. This question never recieved any comment or answer. May I ask your opinion ? Thanks.